# Easily contact all three U.S. Congress people?

Tags: united-states, congress

No one in the U.S. Congress is willing to provide an actual email address to contact your 3, elected representative (2 senators, 1 representative).  Rather, they have you complete a lengthy, web-based form.  If you want to contact all three of your U.S. Congress people, this means a lot of duplicated, data entry.  Does anyone know of a better way?

Comment: Does anyone know when this changed? I last emailed my senators in 2006, about FISA, and got back responses from both.

Answer (score 3):

There is an app, called [Countable](https://www.countable.us/) whereby you can send your opinions and views on certain bills or actions of congress directly to your 3 elected representatives with relatively little friction:

On the [help page](https://www.countable.us/about/us), it lists the functions of the app:

> You can use Countable to:
>
> 1. Read clear and succinct summaries of upcoming and active legislation.
> 2. Directly tell your lawmakers how to vote on those bills by clicking
>    “Yea” or “Nay”.
> 3. Follow up on how your elected officials voted on
>    bills, so you can hold them accountable in the next election cycle.

Comment: Is there an API for the application that our US, congress people use?  If not, I thought about using Ruby and Mechanize, but one of my reps. uses a RECAPTA.

Answer (score 2):

You can look up your Rep [here](https://www.house.gov/representatives/find-your-representative).  While it doesn't let you e-mail them directly, my Rep's search result had a link to his web page with a contact page listing several e-mails.

Having a friend who worked as a congressional staffer, the hot tip is that it's better to call your rep and senators office numbers, which the look up does provide.   Their staff will answer and will take down your information including your comments about what you want to call them about.

Even better is to visit D.C. and walk into their office on the hill while Congress is in session... there might be a line, but a staffer will be on hand and will pass messages along.   The Senators are less likely to meet you as they generally have more to do, but you can always idle in the halls by their office and catch them between travel.   In these cases, it's always best to tell them that you are a constituent as they really don't want the optics of ignoring a constituent on the local news back home.   Usually they only have one office, though if they are a committee chair, they might have two offices (the second being committee office, which might be harder to just walk in on).

The Capitol and it's office buildings are open to the public and entry is free (they do have security checks and "guest" badges at the entrances... there not much different then going to your local court house though.

Finally, if you are visiting D.C., you can arrange a tour with any of your congressional members offices.   Usually your Representative will schedule a little meeting time in his or her office to talk about things with you.  Senators, again, are busy so don't count on that.